# Is there a bandwidth overhead associated with reconnecting to Firebase

Tags: firebase

My application requires periodic updates in the background (Android system). To avoid having continuous connections (which would very quickly saturate the concurrent connections limit), I have my app call goOffline() after an update.

However, doing calculations on my reported bandwidth usage (in the analytics area) is showing much more than I would have expected for the few objects I have listeners registered on. Is the data usage being dominated by calling goOnline() due to extra data being transferred when re-registering the active listeners when my app updates? If this is true I'm going to have problems scaling this app.

Comment: Bandwidth is a simple measure of how much data is transferred. If you take the payload of the data you fetch on each connection, multiply it by the number of times it is sent, you'll have your bandwidth. Most likely, you're just fetching more data than you need and need to [denormalize](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html). Also, a specific use case and some code would help for a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The upload bandwidth is also higher than I would expect. My use-case is this: I have a Firebase reference that contains 4 children (containing 10 bytes strings for each value). My application currently pushes a Set/Map of all 4 reference-value pairs to this location every 60 seconds. Based on this, I would expect an average bandwidth of less than 1 Byte/s (for uploads). However I am seeing usage reports of more like 10 Bytes/s. I am sure that this reference is not being updated more than once every 60 seconds as I can watch the updates in the Forge coming in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's almost certainly negligible.

For example, there's going to be a little overhead in establishing the new TCP session, and even more involved in the SSL negotiation. There's a little more overhead that's specific to Firebase, but nothing beyond the order of magnitude involved in the lower level networking stuff.

So, if you're counting individual bytes, yes you're going to notice. However, in the vast majority of use cases aren't going to notice.